Confused about the stationarity assumption in time series analysis
I understand that in time series analysis one important step is to make the time series stationary which will remove trends and is an assumption for models such as ARMA.
One way to make a time series stationary is take the differences between consecutive time points.
Fine. But if I do this, won't I be left with noise only? So the time series I feed to ARMA will consist of purely noise. This sounds counter-intuitive to me, since we are removing trends which are the interesting properties of the time series.
I read previous posts on this matter, but it's still unclear to me what is it we are actually modelling in the time series if trends, seasonality are removed after making it stationary.


...won't I be left with noise only?

This will only be the case if your original time series $\{x_t\}_{t=1}^T$ is a random walk (with or without a drift) which may be written as ARIMA(0,1,0). Otherwise, you may have, say, an ARIMA(p,1,q) process with $p\neq0$ and/or $q\neq 0$. After differencing that, you will be left with ARMA(p,q).
(Just be aware that differencing a time series that is not integrated to begin with will lead to overdifferencing, which is creating patterns out of thin air.)
Regarding removing trends and such: you should not ignore them but model them separately, as this makes matters easier. So if the original data contains, say, a linear time trend and some deterministic seasonal patterns, decompose your series into trend, seasonal and remainder. Model each one on its own. To forecast, extrapolate the trend, the seasonal pattern, and the remainder each on their own. In the end, put them together; add up if your decomposition was additive or multiply together if it was multiplicative.

Thank you, that was helpful. But I'm also now confused. Nearly all tutorials I watched don't model trends and seasonality separately but only input the differences into the ARMA model and interpret the output model based on those differences. Maybe I should ask another question, but do statistic packages like statsmodels offer a way to do that?

In fact, do you see any usefulness then in modelling the differences? Differencing always looks to me like a random time series, but what I understood from your answer, is that there is still some structure in the time series after differencing (if it's not a random walk), which is interesting and should be modeled, correct?

Packages: probably for some cases but not universally. Manual decomposition and recomposition may be needed. Differencing: yes, there can be structure even after it, and that is what is modelled by the p and q terms of ARIMA(p,1,q). @locus
